# 'ember new' command fails after initializing git. Are there detailed logs anywhere to look at?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm new to ember.js, and node, and npm. I'm having issues running the 'ember new my-project' command. I have a strong suspicion that i've screwed up directory permissions or something by installing something incorrectly but I don't know the best way to go about investigating that.

The environment is as follows: AWS EC2 instance, ubuntu 16.04, nodejs 7.5.0, and npm 4.2.0, bower 1.8.0, ember-cli 2.11.1.

npm, bower, ember were installed with -g and not using sudo as the ember.js docs recommend.

When I run the 'ember new my-project' command I get "Successfully initialized git" and then I get

```
Error creating new application. Removing generated directory `./my-project`
Command failed: /home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --no-optional --loglevel error
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
```

When I run ~ $ npm ls minimatch to check the minimatch piece of the error, i'm not seeing any modules are requiring 2.0.10 so i'm not sure where that is coming from. I'm also not sure if that is actually what's making the whole thing fail.

I also tried running npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2 but that just put it outside the npm@4.2.0 tree as you can see.

```
/home/ubuntu
├── minimatch@3.0.2
└─┬ npm@4.2.0
  ├─┬ fstream-npm@1.2.0
  │ └─┬ fstream-ignore@1.0.5
  │   └── minimatch@3.0.3
  ├─┬ glob@7.1.1
  │ └── minimatch@3.0.3
  ├─┬ init-package-json@1.9.4
  │ └─┬ glob@6.0.4
  │   └── minimatch@3.0.3
  ├─┬ node-gyp@3.5.0
  │ └── minimatch@3.0.3
  └─┬ read-package-json@2.0.4
    └─┬ glob@6.0.4
      └── minimatch@3.0.3
```

What i've tried so far is basically playing with versions - removing and reinstalling nodejs and npm, using different versions (docs and google have recommended different versions of node and npm for use with ember-cli.. I tried node 4.0.0 and npm 2.x.x and 3.x.x)

I also tried using ember-cli 2.11.0 because that version is working properly for in a local VM for me, and running the command with 'sudo'.

Is there a more detailed error log for npm or ember-cli somewhere I can look at?
Can someone point me in the right direction to figure out what's going on here?

Comment: Try it with a node version below 7. Such as node version 6.7.0.

Comment: that minimatch error is usually present, so that's probably not the source of your problem

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a new node version - as mentioned above I had tried node 4.x.x as well.. now I have tried node 6.7.0 with same result. I am using nvm to manage node if that makes a difference at all. Thanks also to @Jure C. for mentioning the minimatch error is usually present. Not concentrating on that piece will make this much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `ember new` with `DEBUG` option:

`DEBUG=* ember new projectname`

this will generate *a lot* of output, but it should help you figure out where it breaks.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately there wasn't anything here that indicated an error, but it did lead me quite far in the right direction. This is not an ember-cli issue as tagged after all.. it's an npm issue. Running 'ember new my-project --skip-npm ; cd my-project ; npm install' reveals more information... npm install is hanging each time while extracting libraries and being killed - and NOT in the same place every time! I found something related here for anyone who finds this: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6023

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jure C. for providing the answer to the question I asked, I found *an* answer to the issue at hand, for anyone who finds this:

From his answer I got to the following: "Running `'ember new my-project --skip-npm ; cd my-project ; npm install'` reveals more information... npm install is hanging each time while extracting libraries and being killed - and NOT in the same place every time"

This led me to believe it was a weird system resources and/or timeout issue or some kind, rather than a permissions or code issue.

Things going wrong:

1) There seemed to be a locally (rather than globally) installed version of npm mucking things up. Not sure when I did this but that's a big whoops. It was not super intuitive where to remove this but eventually I googled my way through it and it helped the process go farther.

2) Turns out the poor little AWS instance was just not up to the task!

```
ulimit -n 2048
```

may have been overkill but allowed all of the extract processes of npm install to finish before being terminated.